# Having different Excel files in different sharepaths, if one file is updated can another will update automatically?

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have two Excel files one is in SharePoint and another is in network shared folder. If SharePoint Excel file updates(the numbers), automatically the network shared folder Excel file also needs to update. As the Excel files is in two different share paths. Is it possible to do that?

--excel file in SharePoint location.(Source File)

--excel file in network shared folder. (Destination file)

Here, the source file is in SharePoint and destination file in network shared folder, which needs to update automatically after the file in SharePoint got updates.

Please help me if that it is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Manyam,
One option to achieve this requirement by creating simple Power Automate flow.
Once the excel file is updated in SharePoint, you can send (replace) the file in Network shared folder.